# Почему не выводится текст в TextView?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой. Не выводится текст в Textview в некоторых версиях Android
[image http://savepic.ru/7396253.png](http://savepic.ru/7396253.png)
Вот как должен выводится:
[image]

Вот код layout`a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/search_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_address"

        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/block_choose_action"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="20dp"

            android:id="@+id/chooseManually">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chooseManually"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>


        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#CCC" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/chooseAuto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/chooseAuto"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#CCC" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/chooseLikePoints"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Любимые адреса"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#CCC" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/chooseInMap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Указать на карте"

                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#CCC" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/chooseLastPoints"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="История адресов"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#CCC" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/chooseTheCity"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="По городу"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>



<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="История"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/textView6"-->
    <!--android:layout_margin="20dp"-->
    <!--android:textSize="17sp" />-->

<!--<ListView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/points"-->
    <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->
    <!--android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"-->
    <!--android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"-->
    <!--android:dividerHeight="20dp"/>-->
```

И из-за чего шапка уходит в контекстное меню?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз явно выставляете цвет фона

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

То явно выставляйте и цвет текста.
Получается так, что на некоторых дивайсах тема поумолчанию использует белый цвет текста, и получается белый текст на белом фоне